# I select a color in Photoshop and it's painting another one

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-conversion, rgb, color-spaces

I select a color in Photoshop and it's painting another one. I've checked RGB color mode and everything, but it seems to continue to change the selected color. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe attach a gif of what is happening or try and explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 13):

Set the tool's blend mode to **Normal** before painting with it.

[image]